# Validate or repaint for this case?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Hi i am having much trouble to repaint a JPanel after hitting the refresh button, in my real app i have Jlabels representing the list of files of the model, each time the refresh button is hit the the list of Jlabels diplayed in the Jpanel must be updated accordingly, i had much trouble doing it, so here i did a simple clean and compilable example, i want that after the refresh button is hit, the JPanel is cleaned (just to let things simple). So i made sure that the update is invoked in the EDT, i did the invalidate manually on the chnaged Jpanel (panConf) and i called the revalidate to the highest comp, the JFrame. Nothing worked so i added repaint and it didn't work too. Could you help me please ?

```
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class PanRepaint extends JFrame {
        private JPanel pan1;
        private JPanel mainPanel;
        private JPanel panConf;
        private JFrame dis;
    public PanRepaint() {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("ZAZAZA");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Update");
        dis = this;
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        panConf = new JPanel();
                        panConf.invalidate();
                        //dis.invalidate();
                        dis.validate();
                        dis.repaint();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        panConf = new JPanel();
        pan1 = new JPanel();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        panConf.add(label1);
        panConf.add(label2);
        pan1.add(btn);
        mainPanel.add(panConf);
        mainPanel.add(pan1);
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PanRepaint pr = new PanRepaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here at all..what's the end game?

Comment: I want to display an empty Frame after the button is hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new JPanel in the ActionListener's actionPerformed method but add it to nothing, in particular you add it to no container whose container hierarchy leads to a top-level window (here your JFrame), so changes to it will not be reflected in the GUI.

I suspect that you are under the fallacy that if you have a variable refer to a new object and change the new object's state, here panConf, that you will somehow change the state of the original object that the variable previously referred to, but that's not how Java works. The original JPanel that panConf refered to at the program start still exists and still sits in the GUI unchanged. The key to this is that you must understand the difference between a reference variable and an object (or reference). This is a key Java concept that might take some effort to fully get, but is worth the effort.

Instead simply remove the components held by the original panConf JPanel:

```
  btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do not create a new JPanel here
        panConf.removeAll();
        panConf.revalidate();
        panConf.repaint();
     }
  });
```

---

Or better still, use a **[CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)** to swap views.

Also, there's no need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and a Runnable queue this on the EDT. The code is already being called on the event thread.

Comment: How is that ? i am still referring to the class variable panConf, when i make = new JPanel, it only changes its content.

Comment: @user2548720: no,  you're not still referring to the original JPanel. You're creating a **NEW** JPanel and having the same variable refer to it. Changes to this new JPanel will have no effect on the JPanel that panConf originally referred to and which is still sitting in the GUI. This has nothing to do with Swing and is a core Java concept that you must understand: the difference between variables and objects.